# Spring custom authentication token never GCed

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, memory-leaks

I've implemented custom AuthenticationProvider:

```
 @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new PassthroughAuthentication(name, password, grantedAuths);
    }
```

PassthroughAuthentication:

```
public class PassthroughAuthentication implements Authentication {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;
    private boolean authenticated;
    private Object password;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;

    public PassthroughAuthentication(String username, String password, List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities){
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.grantedAuthorities = grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return new User(username, password.toString(), grantedAuthorities );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return authenticated;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.authenticated = isAuthenticated;       
    }   
}
```

And I can see using VisualVM that the `PassthroughAuthentication` object with every request stays in memory and is never GC-ed.

But my requests are stateless and I've disabled Session management.

What can be holding this class?

Comment: What is this PassthroughAuthentication? Have you tried with UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva That is my custom class, I've updated question with code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out.

Instead of:

```
http.sessionManagement().disable();
```

Stateless session creation solves it:

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```